serverless Region changed? An error occurred while fetching the SSM parameter "/serverless-framework/state/s3-bucket"
Very recently, my deployment system started acting weird and I'm dead in the water until I find a fix.
Original error:
An error occurred while fetching the SSM parameter "/serverless-framework/state/s3-bucket": 
User: arn:aws:iam::0123456789:user/insert-real-user-here is not authorized to perform: 
ssm:GetParameter on resource:
arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:025132599338:parameter/serverless-framework/state/s3-bucket 
because no identity-based policy allows the ssm:GetParameter action

Thing is, my serverless.yml file didn't change, and it points to a different region. (I.e. we don't use us-east-1).
ChatGPT and the docs haven't helped me debug what changed, and the change was sudden.
I've been trying to edit serverless.yml to specify a custom Deployment Bucket. I can see the name of the usual bucket within the region that I actually use. I've tried making other buckets. No joy.
So the simple question is, what would folks do next in order to debug this?
I have tried adding a state: to the top level of my serverless.yml file, and added my own S3 bucket as a parameter there, but I'm not sure that I'm using that correctly.

I ended up fixing this by adding a bunch of permissions to a user that didn't need to be there before. I also had to add the deployment bucket name to serverless.yml where it wasn't needed before. Comments are still invited, in case there's something obvious that was happening.

I do have the similar problem that occurs today. Mine situation is even simpler. I am deploying to the localstack by the serverless-localstack plugin. It works all good last week but it failed today. I didn't change anything at all.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
